# tf.metrics.accuracy producing higher accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm currently experimenting with the new high level tf.contrib.learn APIs in Tensorflow by porting over features from the inception-v3 retrain script from this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining#distortions):

However, I'm currently getting a 97% accuracy on the modified script which is much better than the 91% accuracy on the original.

May I know if this happened because of a better underlying implementation in the tf.contrib.learn APIs or if I computed the accuracy differently in the 2 scripts?

These are some code snippets to make it clearer.

Method 1: Modified script

```
# Calculate accuracy as additional eval metric
eval_metric_ops = {
    "accuracy": tf.metrics.accuracy(targets, one_hot_classes)
}
```

Method 2: Original retrain.py

```
with tf.name_scope('accuracy'):
with tf.name_scope('correct_prediction'):
    prediction = tf.argmax(result_tensor, 1)
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(
        prediction, tf.argmax(ground_truth_tensor, 1))
with tf.name_scope('accuracy'):
    evaluation_step = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
```

Comment: Sounds like it's just due to randomness in the learning process.

Comment: This happens in every single run. Accuracy is always 91-92 vs 96-97

Comment: Hmm, you're right, it's a bit less random than I was thinking. I think the issue is actually that `tf.metrics.accuracy` expects class numbers rather than one hot encodings (i.e. you need the `argmax` ops that the original has).

Comment: @AllenLavoie you're right too, i tried passing tf.argmax(targets,1) and classes into tf.metrics.accuracy and it gave the same accuracy level of ~91%. I always assumed, based on the documentation, that as long as the labels and predictions had the same shape it should work fine.

Comment: @AllenLavoie may i also know why do the new tf.contrib.learn high-level API train faster than the original retrain.py using low-level APIs?

Comment: Guess #1 would be the input pipeline (it's essentially forced to be through TensorFlow ops/queues when using Estimators, which can be more efficient than feeding from Python). Guess #2 would be evaluation happening in a background thread (so that it doesn't block training).